# Creating a file with a hole

Tags: c, unix, filesystems

I was trying to create a file with a hole using a textbook code and modifying it slightly. However, something must've gone wrong, since I don't see any difference between both files in terms of size and disk blocks.

Code to create a file with a hole (Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment)

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <fcntl.h>

char    buf1[] = "abcdefghij";
char    buf2[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ";

int
main(void)
{
    int     fd;

    if ((fd = creat("file.hole", FILE_MODE)) < 0)
        printf("creat error");

    if (write(fd, buf1, 10) != 10)
        printf("buf1 write error");
    /* offset now = 10 */

    if (lseek(fd, 16384, SEEK_SET) == -1)
        printf("lseek error");
    /* offset now = 16384 */

    if (write(fd, buf2, 10) != 10)
        printf("buf2 write error");
    /* offset now = 16394 */

    exit(0);
}
```

My code, creating a file basically full of abcdefghij's.

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>

char    buf1[] = "abcdefghij";
char    buf2[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ";

int
main(void)
{
    int     fd;

    if ((fd = creat("file.nohole", FILE_MODE)) < 0)
        printf("creat error");

    while(lseek(fd,0,SEEK_CUR)<16394)
    {
        if (write(fd, buf1, 10) != 10)
        printf("buf1 write error");
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Printing both files I get the expected output. However, their size is identical.

```
{linux1:~/dir} ls -ls *hole
17 -rw-------+ 1 user se 16394 Sep 14 11:42 file.hole
17 -rw-------+ 1 user se 16400 Sep 14 11:33 file.nohole
```

Comment: Maybe 16384 is too small, try something like 1048576.

Comment: That worked. Very naive of me to use textbook provided values that were relevant probably 10 years ago... Thanks.
if anyone curious:
`259 -rw-------+ 1 user se 1048586 Sep 14 11:56 file.hole
1155 -rw-------+ 1 user se 1048580 Sep 14 11:56 file.nohole`

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand what is meant by a "hole".

What it means is that you write some number of bytes, skip over some other number of bytes, then write more bytes.  The bytes you don't explicitly write in between are set to 0.

The file itself doesn't have a hole in it, i.e. two separate sections.  It just has bytes with 0 in them.

If you were to look at the contents of the first file, you'll see it has "abcdefghij" followed by 16373 (16384 - 10 - 1) bytes containing the value 0 (not the character "0") followed by ABCDEFGHIJ.

Comment: Not quite. You are right that the bytes inbetween are set to 0, and I used to od command to verify that. However, there is also a benefit of smaller number of blocks used. In the corrected program, *hole file used 259 blocks while the .nohole used 1155 blocks.

Comment: @DR29, then that is a clever filesystem that somehow keeps track of the blocks with zero, "inserting" them upon read (or it compressed the file).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: there might be clever filesystems like that but the standard unix filesystems are not so clever. They simply don't write blocks to disk unless the program actually writes them. If you write a block of 0s, it will get written to disk; if you advance the write pointer and then write, then there won't be any disk representation of the blocks you skipped over. When reading, if a block isn't on disk, it is assumed to be all 0s. As simple and dumb as that.

Comment: @rici: see Serge's reference: the empty blocks are represented in metadata. The metadata maps the block-to-disk address (inode, FAT) and maps your "if a block isn't on disk" which thus is not so "as simple and dumb as that"

Comment: @paul: the metadata indicates which physical block (if any) each logical block of the file maps to. If no data has been written to a block, it is not mapped. If zeros are written to a block, it is mapped. Contrast that with an actual compressing filesystem, which might be able to notice that a block was full of zeros (or other compressible contents). That would be a lot more sophisticated (and experience shows, lesz robust). Smart and dumb are a bit value-laden; I actually usually find dumb solutions to be cleverer.